# Wordpress redirects to wrong page after renaming

Tags: wordpress

I was changing the structure of my wordpress page making some changes to names of the pages. I renamed the pages e.g.

```
location > gallery
howtogethere > location
```

Now, I think, wordpress seems to be smart and whats to catch everything that goes to `location` and forwards it to `gallery`. The problem is, there is a new page `location`. When I try to access `location` via `domain.com/location` I get redirected to `gallery`.

The question is where are those redirects stored and how can I delete them?

Answer (score 0):

Check the permalinks below Page title and if that is not changed to your changed page name change that and your problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

It is very possible that this is a cache issue. You can try deleting the cache in your browser, or you can try visiting your page from a browser that has never visited your page before.

It is also possible that it is a server side cache issue. I do not know if WordPress caches things like this, but if they do you can assume it will start working as expected eventually.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to clear cache also install that plugin to manage and create redirects:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/